# Asp.Net Core ControllerBase.Response, Where's the sourcecode?

Tags: c#, github, asp.net-core-mvc

It's awesome that ASP.NET Core is now open source, especially since the docs are still being written but often I have a hard time locating the code that I want to review.

So for example, I'd like to see how the controller implements `Response.Redirect` but where is the code?

I was able to locate the RC2 version of the code for the ControllerBase on GitHub here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs

And by cloning the github.com/aspnet/Mvc respository I was able to use VS2015 to learn that the `HttpResponse` class used by the `ControllerBase` is an `abstract` class.  But I'm now at a dead end.

Where is the code for the concrete implementation of `HttpResponse` that is used by the `ControllerBase`?  And here's the really big question: How did you locate that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps someone else.

The source code for HttpResponse class is found here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpResponse.cs but it's an abstract class not a concrete one.  It turns out that the concrete implementation is a class called `DefaultHttpResponse` and the code for that class is located here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/DefaultHttpResponse.cs

One of the reason this source code was hard to locate is that it's part of a project that isn't included in the ASP.NET Core MVC repository on GitHub.  While the MVC repository does include lots of projects, the project that contains `HttpResponse` and `DefaultHttpResponse` isn't among them.

So how did I find the location of the code?  I was navigating the ASP.NET Core MVC source code in Visual Studio and I eventually noticed that when I hit F12 to navigate to the code for `HttpResponse` from the `ControllerBase` class that it indicated the following at the top of the page `Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` in light gray.

This then got me googling for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` and sure enough it's located in a different Git Repository.  Once I cloned that repository, I could use Visual Studio to search for HttpResponse.  Then I right clicked on the class name to go to implementation. That took me to the `DefaultHttpResponse` class which is the concrete implementation of the `HttpResponse` class. Yea!

I guess one of the things that threw me is that the name of the git repository ends in "Abstractions".  Initially I figured such a repository would just contain interfaces and such, but it turns out that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` repository contains contains several projects and some of them contain lots of implementations for classes having to do with the `HttpContext` which includes `HttpResponse` and it's concrete implementation as `DefaultHttpResponse`

[image: screen shot]